# Is getting users OS from user agent reliable?

Tags: php, parsing, operating-system, user-agent

So currently on my website I log users `OS` when they register an account. And then they can view it (their `OS` that was logged upon registration) on their "account page".

But my question is, is getting users `OS` from parsing `useragent` in PHP reliable? For example I get users `useragent` via this `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` in php, then parse it to extract their `OS` from the `useragent`. Can I rely on this being accurate for legitimate users?

I don't really care if hackers can spoof the `useragent`, all I really am wondering is if this (`$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`) will give me the users accurate `OS` from legitimate (non hacker) site visitors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes its reliable for non hacker user.

**More Explaination**

The user agent string is a text that the browsers themselves send to the webserver to identify themselves, so that websites can send different content based on the browser or based on browser compatibility.

Mozilla is a browser rendering engine (the one at the core of Firefox) and the fact that Chrome and IE contain the string Mozilla/4 or /5 identifies them as being compatible with that rendering engine.

You can also use [get_browser()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php) function of php.

Answer (score 4):

You appear to be asking whether you can trust this field to be reliable when it's reliable? Well, yes, you can; when it's reliable, it's reliable.

But these times are rare. You don't need to be a "hacker" to spoof a User Agent. A simple browser extension will do it, or one extra argument in your `wget` or `curl` command if the request is scripted.

**User agent is 100% fallible and you should not rely on it for anything useful.**

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time it is pretty reliable, in that most people can't be bothered to change this information. So using it for purely secondary, and ease-of-use, functionality is OK.
Especially in cases like these, where you use it to fill out the "default" values. Which the user have an option to change if wrong.

However, as it *can* be changed/spoofed by anyone who knows a little bit about HTTP and/or web browsers, you must not rely upon it for anything security related. There are quite a few browsers even, which will let the user change their user-agent string at will.
That includes using the user-agent string in an attempt to identify a user. As it is trivially easy to copy the headers, and spoof your own.

Use of SSL would increase the difficulty slightly. Still, in order to get all of the headers from your users (or admins), all an attacker would need is to post a link on your site to a server of his own. After which he could do whatever he wanted with his own.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make your UI more friendly. Lets say: "Is user on Chromer?" then show him some usefull info. Then its 100% reliable and very usefull. I don't care how friendly my UI is for hackers.

In some cases, for example ... lets say that for some reason you would like to block every one but Chrome owner,.. you can't rely on it.